# how to call function from another page in java?

Tags: java, android

i have defined all my java files in packages... i have one function which i have defined on some page and i just want to use it on another page... how would i do that...

Comment: page? didn't you mean package?

Comment: Buddy, they are not functions, they are known as methods in Java. You need some tutorials, Google for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I understand from your question and comment is that you want to call a method from a class defined in other file. Here is an example;

```
public class FirstClass {

    /**
     * Shows the passed string on console.
     * @param msg String containing the message to be displayed.
     */
    public void showMessage(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Saved this class in a file named FirstClass.java. It contains a method `showMessage()` which we will call from other class defined in CallerClass.java source file.

```
public class CallerClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Created an object of FirstClass class
        FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass();

        firstClass.showMessage("Welcome to Java.");
    }
}
```

This is the class which contains the main method. We have called the `showMessage(String)` method from here using the object of `FirstClass` class.
Functions in Java are called methods, and they can be invoked by creating the object of their class. Actually methods can also be called without creating the object but they must be static. Hop you got the idea. Get some good books or tutorials to understand the basics of OOP and Java.